# Factoring into a product with three term

Tags: polynomials, factoring, cubics

I want to solve the following equation:
$$144s^3-408s^2+349s-85 = 0$$
I know that the solution is:
$$(s-1)(12s-17)(12s-5)=0$$
which implies gives, $s=1$ or $s=\dfrac{17}{12} $ or $s=\dfrac{5}{12}$.

However, I don't understand how to factor the left hand side into a product of three terms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One can use the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find one root and then perform long division

Answer (score 2):

If you know that s=1 is solution, you might try to rewrite $144s^3-144s^2-264s^2+264s+85s-85=0$, then you factor with s-1